# HTML anchor tag (in jquery mobile) doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, anchor

I'm making a mobile web page in jquery mobile, and I'm wondering why the html anchor tag `[<a name="one">` as your anchor, and then `<a href="#one">]` works fine in iOS, but doesn't work on Android.
Why not?

Comment: Named anchors are discouraged these days. Add an `id` of "one" to the element you're targeting and see what happens...

Comment: Dear Tieson T., a detailed examples can you write? Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning an `id` to the element you're targeting (the one the page should scroll/jump to), and setting the link's `href` to that `id`, like this:

```
<a href="#second">Link</a>
<div id="first">
    ...
</div>
<div id="second">
    ...
</div>
```